# GPT4All add context

Tags: python, gpt-4

i want to add a context before send a prompt to my gpt model.
i use orca-mini-3b.ggmlv3.q4_0 model.

this is my code, i add a PromptTemplate to RetrievalQA.from_chain_type, but when a send a prompt it's not work, in this example the bot not call me "bob"

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from langchain import PromptTemplate
from langchain.chains import RetrievalQA
from langchain.embeddings import HuggingFaceEmbeddings
from langchain.callbacks.streaming_stdout import StreamingStdOutCallbackHandler
from langchain.prompts import ChatPromptTemplate
from langchain.vectorstores import Chroma
from langchain.llms import GPT4All, LlamaCpp
import chromadb
import time
import os

def main():

    embeddings_model_name="model_transformers/all-MiniLM"
    persist_directory="db"
    os.environ["PERSIST_DIRECTORY"] = persist_directory
    from constants import CHROMA_SETTINGS
    model_type="GPT4All"
    model_path="orca-mini-3b.ggmlv3.q4_0 (1).bin"
    model_n_ctx=1000
    model_n_batch=8
    target_source_chunks=4
    # Parse the command line arguments
    embeddings = HuggingFaceEmbeddings(model_name=embeddings_model_name)
    chroma_client = chromadb.PersistentClient(settings=CHROMA_SETTINGS , path=persist_directory)
    db = Chroma(persist_directory=persist_directory, embedding_function=embeddings, client_settings=CHROMA_SETTINGS, client=chroma_client)
    retriever = db.as_retriever(search_kwargs={"k": target_source_chunks})
    # activate/deactivate the streaming StdOut callback for LLMs
    callbacks = [StreamingStdOutCallbackHandler()]
    # Prepare the LLM
    match model_type:
        case "LlamaCpp":
            llm = LlamaCpp(model_path=model_path, max_tokens=model_n_ctx, n_batch=model_n_batch, callbacks=callbacks, verbose=False)
        case "GPT4All":
            llm = GPT4All(model=model_path, max_tokens=model_n_ctx, backend='gptj', n_batch=model_n_batch, callbacks=callbacks, verbose=False)
        case _default:
            # raise exception if model_type is not supported
            raise Exception(f"Model type {model_type} is not supported. Please choose one of the following: LlamaCpp, GPT4All")

    prompt_template = """
    My name is Bob, you must call me Bob
    {context}"""

    prompt = PromptTemplate(
        input_variables=["context"],
        template=prompt_template
    )

    chain_type_kwargs = {"prompt": prompt}
    qa = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(llm=llm, chain_type="stuff", retriever=retriever,
                                     chain_type_kwargs=chain_type_kwargs,
                                     return_source_documents=False)
    # Interactive questions and answers
    print("start")
    while True:
        query = input("\nEnter a query: ")
        if query == "exit":
            break
        if query.strip() == "":
            continue

        # Get the answer from the chain
        start = time.time()
        res = qa(query)
        answer, docs = res['result'], []
        end = time.time()

        print(f"\n> Answer (took {round(end - start, 2)} s.):")
        print(answer)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

in this example, i sent "what is my name ?", i want to outpout: "your name is bob", but i have this:
`Enter a query: what is my name ?

> Answer (took 34.79 s.):

Project Administrator | The user who will become the self-care role for the project. This user has access to all parts of the project and can perform actions such as creating resources, updating configurations, and deleting resources. Project Name | The name of the project on OpenShift. It must be in lowercase and contain only letters and numbers. There is a blacklist to prevent certain characters from being used.`

why ?

i want to add history context for the conversation of the bot